# PHP : check if row value is image or pdf file then echo accordingly

Tags: php, image, pdf

i am storing image path  in  database and getting proper output if the row value is image but:

first my question is first i want to check if result $row ['image'] is  .jpg then echo image  tag and display value else if  $row['pdf '] is  .pdf file then display pdf file  how to accomplish it  as there are number of other variables to be echoed ?? before and after this which are working fine any guidance will be highly appreciated with only please

Comment: you would either need to code something to check the extension, or put some sort of indicator on the database that you could use to distinguish them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write an ends with function something like this

```
function endsWith($filename, $ext){
    $extLength = strlen($ext);
    if($extLength){
        return substr($filename, -extLength) === $ext;
    }
    return true;
}

//Function to add quotes to string for neatness
function dq($string){
    return "\"$string\"";
}
```

then do some like

```
If(endsWith($row['xxx'], ".jpg")){
    echo '<img src='. dq($row['xxx']). />];
}
else{
    //display pdf
}
```

Make sure your storing the URL in the database properly by using filters to encode and decode it. As for displaying the PDF file that's browser dependent useless you use a third party library.

EDIT: fixed errors in code. Sorry about that.

Comment: sorry for the late reply yes it actually helped thanks a ton